# SQL Query optimization - determining unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sqlperformance

I need to determine students (student_id) with not unique person_id and return another column with 0 when not unique, with 1 when unique.

Here's what I have:

```
Select 
    student_id, 0
FROM
    PERSON
WHERE 
    PERSON.person_id in ( 
        SELECT PERSON.person_id
        FROM PERSON
        WHERE PERSON.person_id<>''
        GROUP BY PERSON.person_id
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    )
UNION
Select 
    student_id, 1
FROM
    PERSON
WHERE 
    PERSON.person_id not in (
         SELECT PERSON.person_id
         FROM PERSON
         WHERE PERSON.person_id<>''
         GROUP BY PERSON.person_id
         HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    )
```

Sample data: http://pastebin.com/EcqQU88J
MS SQL Server

Is there any more efficient way to do the job?

Comment: `SELECT student_id,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM #PERSON
GROUP BY student_id`  [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406875)

Comment: @lad2025 It returns only "1" in second column.

Comment: So? It means that in your data for every student ID it is only unique person_id. Share example(for data you provided) when it should return 0

Comment: @lad2025 Please take look at my [working but little to slow example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406953/working-but-slow-query). First 3 persons have unique person_id, 4th and 5th person in results doesn't have unique person_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT person_id, COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) AS r
    FROM #PERSON
    GROUP BY person_id
)
SELECT student_id, CASE WHEN r = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM #PERSON p
JOIN cte c
  ON p.person_id = c.person_id
-- ORDER BY student_id
```

You should add indexes to your `PERSON` table.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406965)**</kbd>

Comment: Great! It looks ok. Thank You :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might be more efficient.  I think it's simpler.

```
select student_id
, case when personIds = 1 then 0 else 1 end notUnique
from 
(select student_id
, count(distinct person_id) personIDs
from person
where person_id <> ''
group by student_id
) temp
```

Comment: It returns only "0" in second column.